# PHP Add properties from Extended Class / Parents' Class

Tags: php, extend

i have a project where i try i implement the properties from the parents class(vehicle.php) into landvehicle.php .All properties are set to public. My goal is to use the properties from Vehicle for Landvehicle, for $landOne ($height) in this particular case.

Vehicle.php :

```
<?php

class Vehicle
{
    public $length;
    public $height;
    public $color;
    public $weight;
    public $price;
    public $range;


    public function __construct($length, $height, $color, $weight, $price, $range)
    {
        $this->length = $length;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->color = $color;
        $this->weight = $weight;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->range = $range;
    }
    public function addHeight()
    {
        return "$this->height is the height";
    }


}

$userVehicleOne = new Vehicle('2.5 Meter', '1,3 Meter', 'red', '1800kg', '40.000€', '450km');
```

Landvehicle.php:

```
<?php

include 'vehicle.php';

class Landvehicle extends Vehicle
{
    public $amountWheels;
    public $movementType;

    public function __construct($amountWheels, $movementType)
    {
        $this->amountWheels = $amountWheels;
        $this->movementType = $movementType;
    }

}

$landOne = new Landvehicle ('4', 'flexible');



echo $landOne->addHeight('1.50Meter')
```

I've tried to use the addHeight function from Vehicle.php to set the height to 1.50 Meters for $landOne

Comment: There's a lot of misunderstanding and poor design in your code here. Rather than someone giving you a lengthy answer about how OOP works in PHP, you should study some more on your own - there are endless resources available out there. You're not setting the `$height` parameter anywhere from `LandVehicle`, you're not calling the parent constructor, and in fact both classes might as well be completely unrelated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in addHeight method you dont accept any params and in Landvehicle.php you passed 1.50Meter as first parameters and this is incorrect. remove your addHeight method and replace it with following code:

```
public function addHeight($height)
{
    $this->height = $height;
    return "$this->height is the height";
}
```